# View within View (Android)

Tags: android, view

So I can pass a custom View to the setContentView() and it fills the users screen by default(right?), but if I define a TextField within my custom views constructor it won't display. Even if I change my custom View to a custom ViewGroup and use its addView() method.

So what am I missing here?

Also, whats the equivalent of System.out.println() in android to get some feedback?

Comment: Its tough to help without seeing your code.  Can you add some to your question?

Answer (score 1):

for print statements, used Log.d("*Name of the filter"*, "Text to be printed here"). Also, why aren't you defining your view in an XML file and adding the textview inside there? it is usually not a good idea to use addview because it makes laying things out more difficult (not as many options for location and size, etc.)